# Spurious character in favorite tags

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tags

It looks like the fix implemented for [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98131/236798) breaks Opera in favor of Chrome.  That may be a reasonable tradeoff, since I'm guessing more folks are browsing in Chrome.  But is there a stronger way to solve the problem that renders correctly in all browsers?

[image: spurious character in favorite tag]

As noted [here](http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=289533) system fonts don't always support the zero-width space character.

EDIT: It's probably related to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192911/tag-favorite-ignore-normal-character-shows-a-box-if-helvetica-not-present?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

I can't repro this on the current version of Opera.

Comment: Are you testing on a system that has Helvetica installed?  It wouldn't show up there if my guess is correct.